# SimpleImputer TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am having a problem when I try to impute this data set. When I try to gather object class items to impute them, it throws this error.

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

impNumeric = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
impCategorical = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, 
                               strategy='most_frequent')

objects = group1.select_dtypes(include=np.object)
imputed = impCategorical.fit(objects).transform(objects) # line error
```

Comment: Pleaes post the full stack trace.

Comment: what's group1? Please include whatever is needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Because `object` is the default container that can hold strings, but also a mix of any objects. so a Series of `[1, 'foo']` gets stored as on object just like a Series of `['foo', 'bar']`, the problem being logical comparisons (`<`) among the elements in the first list do not make sense.

Comment: @ALollz how would you fix this issue?

Comment: @Roy2012 Group1 is my dataset.

Comment: I know it's your data set ... but one can't reproduce the issue you're facing without it. Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I think the problem is what @ALollz suggested. @Roy2012 there are different class types in these objects. The only method that works for me is to do `np.numeric` however that only imputes numeric columns.

Comment: `np.nan` is a float object.  I don't know the details of `Simpleimputer` (and the lack of traceback doesn't help), but I doubt if it will work with a mix of string and integer inputs.  The error says it's trying to compare objects that can't be compared.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I found the fix!
The explanation of `object` being able to contain types was a good hint.
In my case, the error was: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'`. I took a closer look:

```
df[df['categorical_column'].isnull()][categorical_columns]
```

Indeed, I had a mixture of `str` and `None`.
In my case, the fix was explicitly stating the `missing_values` argument:

```
imputer_mod = SimpleImputer(missing_values=None, strategy='most_frequent')
```

In you case, you're having a mixture of `str` and `int`. Check how your missing values are encoded (perhaps by a `0` / `-1` / `-99` etc.) and adjust your `missing_values` argument accordsaingly. This should fix the issue!